# It is possible to read databases of different versions of the SQL server compact edition using one application?

Tags: sql-server-ce

Given:

- DLLs of SQL Server compact editions 3.5 and 4.0
- Several read-only database files, some belong to 3.5 and some to 4.0

Is it possible to query these database files without uprading (the files are read-only)? I know there is such a thing as registration-free (aka side-by-side) COM, but I do not know the details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I do that in my VS add-in. I have implemented 3 projects (= 3 .NET DLL files), one is an Interface definition, second is an implementation against this interface referenceing 3.5 and third is an implementation referencing 4.0 - but maybe you can simply use my scripting API, it has methods to return query results also - http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

I do this in my SQL Compact Query Analyzer project. You can check it out and download the source code from http://sqlcequery.codeplex.com/